# Autoincrement through IDENTITY in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm trying to do autoincrement in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio by using `identity`, but I'm not able to fill in values for incremental column ID. What to fill in insert values?

Part of my code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE G_Members
(
ID int(4) IDENTITY(0001, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
Jméno varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Nick varchar(20) NULL,
Příjmení varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Pohlaví char(1) NOT NULL,
Datum_Narození date NULL
);

INSERT INTO G_Members VALUES
( 'Martin', 'Mates', 'Škorník', 'M', 01-AUG-1978);
INSERT INTO G_Members VALUES
(NEXT VALUE FOR G_Members.ID, 'Ondřej', ' ', 'Panenka', 'M', 29-MAR-1983, );
```

Comment: You don't need to pass any value for `G_Members.ID`

Comment: You need to learn to distinguish between client tools (such as SQL Server Management Studio) and the server itself. What you're asking is an SQL Server question. It doesn't matter whether you're accessing SQL Server via Management Studio, OSQL, SQLCMD, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `Auto Increment Column` you cannot insert any data for that column. You have to modify your SQL-Statement in such a way that you specify all other columns and obmit the `IDENTITY` column. This is achieved as follows:

```
INSERT INTO G_Members (Jméno,Nick,Příjmení, Pohlaví,Datum_Narození) VALUES ( 'Martin', 'Mates', 'Škorník', 'M', 01-AUG-1978);
```

SQL Server will insert a new value for the `Id` column.

Edit:
I suggest you to use `nvarchar` over `varchar` because then you will be able to store unicode values. Especially for your language this would be a better choice

Comment: Tahnk you very much. This really helped. I will change also datatype.